# Candy Machine Showing 'Your Price' as undefined, Sugar Update not working

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex, candy-machine, solana-cli

When I load the candy machine UI site it now randomly shows the "Your Price" as undefined (`candyMachine.state.price`). And I am seeing this error now when trying to run `sugar update`:

'Failed to deserialize Candy Machine account : RPC request error: cluster version query failed: error sending request for url (https://ssc-dao.genesysgo.net/): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (os error 10060).'

This mint has been running for a couple of days now. I haven't touched anything since Sunday so I'm thinking it's just temporarily down? Is there a fix for it while the mint is running or do I just wait for the RPC URL to start working again?

Comment: Can you please share the candy machine id and also try to use a different RPC?

Comment: I don't know if should share the ID while the mint is running. What would be a different RPC to use? And can I do that without affecting the mint currently running?

Comment: Its back up and running now.